# Setting field value 'user' in view before form validation

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying to set field value 'user' in view before validation as you can see in my example below. But I still get the validation message user is required, suggesting it's not being set. What I'm I doing wrong?

thanks,

**view.py**

```
def add_batch(request):
    # If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = BatchForm(data=request.POST, initial={'user': request.user})
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            # Clean all data and add to var data.
            data = form.cleaned_data
            groups = data['groups'].split(",")
            for item in groups:
                batch = Batch(content=data['content'],
                              group=Group.objects.get(pk=item),
                              user=request.user
                              )
                batch.save()
            return redirect(batch.get_send_conformation_page())
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render_to_response('sms/sms_standard.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**form.py**

```
class BatchForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Batch

    def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            form_choices = Group.objects.for_user(user)
        else:
            form_choices = Group.objects.all()
        self.fields['groups'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
            queryset=form_choices
        )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) explains, `initial` values are not used to set data in forms, they are only used for displaying, well, initial values.

If you don't want to display the user but want to set it automatically, the best thing to do is to exclude the user field from the ModelForm altogether and set it in the view when you save. Alternatively, since you are passing it in as a parameter for other reasons, you could perhaps add that to the POST data:

```
def __init__(self, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BatchForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    if user is not None:
        if self.data:
            self.data['user'] = user
```

Comment: O I forgot about 'exclude' and thanks for explaining about the init

Comment: Isn't `self.data` an immutable?

Answer (score 0):

```
form = BatchForm(request.user, request.POST)
# Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
if form.is_valid():
    [.........]
```

Comment: that still seems to give This field is required 'user'.

Comment: I think it should be `form = BatchForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)`

Comment: @Bibhas I'm very sure that my answer for passing user value is correct because I also did this in my project.

Comment: @catherine his `__init__` function requires a `user` paramter.

Comment: @Bibhas yeah I know I see it. My answer pass the user value, it doesn't have to user=request.user. It's understood.